# Is this a valid use of store in a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have I done a proper use of store in below code?

Am I allowed to use `store.dispatch()` directly instead of using connect from react-redux library inorder to use actions on store or should I just use connect ?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../store/store';
import removeTodo from '../actions/removeTodo';
const deleteChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.elements);
}
const renderData = ({ todo, id, description, isCompleted }) => {
    if (!isCompleted) {
        return (
            <div key={id}>
                <h4>{todo}
                    <span className="float-right">
                        <a href="#" title="Remove" onClick={() => {
                            store.dispatch(removeTodo({todo, description, id }));
                        }}><i className="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                    </span>
                </h4>
                <p>{description}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return false;
}
const RenderRemaining = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Tasks: </h2>
            <hr />
            {props.detail.map(renderData)}
        </div>
    );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        detail: state.todoReducer
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RenderRemaining);
```

Comment: `redux` zealots would say it's not recommended. But I see no issue there. `store` is an object with a bunch of methods. Just like anything else in JavaScript.

Comment: Looks good redux-wise.  I would just rename `detail` to `list` as that what it is although I don't have full context. And you can use dispatch directly, but it's recommended to use mapDispatchToProps.